# Log the actual data sent in the request in SoapUI

Tags: logging, groovy, soapui

I have the request which uses in-line script:

```
<Req>
 <TransactionId>${= new Date().format("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS")}</TransactionId>
</Req>
```

How can I log value of TransactionId or whole request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Script Assertion` for the same test step.

And add the below code to achieve the same i.e., logs the entire request:

```
log.info context.rawRequest
```

In order to get the `TransactionId`, you can parse the request and extract the value with below code:

```
def xmlRequest = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.rawRequest)
def tId = xmlRequest.'**'.find {it.name = 'TransactionId'}?.text()
log.info "Transaction id sent in the request is: $tId"
```